# Why is the perl hash overwriting previous data?

Tags: perl, hash, key

So, I'm writing data into my hash which is `%errordata`. It looks like this

```
sub openfile
{
 if (open my $data, "<", $filename)
   {
    my $line = <$data>;
    print "Error: $line";
    my $dir = cwd;
    print "$dir\n";
    $errordata{$line} = $dir;
    while (my($keys,$values) = each %errordata) {
     print "$keys in $values\n";
    }
}
```

The first two print output that I got looks something like this

```
FIRST 
ERROR: quick brown fox
/abc/efg/hij/klm
SECOND
ERROR: quick brown fox
/abc/efg/hij/gvb
```

But every time it encounters the same output it overwrites it but I want to save the path because it may be different.

```
FIRST 
quick brown fox in /abc/efg/hij/klm
SECOND
quick brown fox in /abc/efg/hij/klm
```

Should I use `push (@{%hash{"KEYNAME"} }, "new value")` ? If so, can anyone elaborate on this? I'm not sure how to go on about this.
Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Hash key is unique (hash can have only one element with unique key). If you want to save a several values under same key you need assign an array to this particular key -- `push @{$hash{$key}}, $value;`. Tutorial [Perl Hash](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-hash/).

Comment: Tutorial [Perl Hash](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_hashes.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl hash assumes that each key is unique. If you would like to store more than one value or data structure under one key you need apply some logic how to achieve desired result.

Please see the following demo code to sort teachers and students from incoming data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %people;
my $re = qr/(\S+)\s+(.*)/;

while( <DATA> ) {
    my($title,$name) = /$re/;
    push @{$people{$title}}, $name;
}

say Dumper(\%people);

while( my($title,$group) = each %people ) {
    say ucfirst $title . ':';
    say "\t$_" for @{$group};
}

__DATA__
teacher Alex Trump
student Amanda Torry
student Nick Popler
student Jonny Sleeper
student Natalie Simpson
teacher George Magic
student Tom Smarty
teacher Pat Golder
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'teacher' => [
                         'Alex Trump',
                         'George Magic',
                         'Pat Golder'
                       ],
          'student' => [
                         'Amanda Torry',
                         'Nick Popler',
                         'Jonny Sleeper',
                         'Natalie Simpson',
                         'Tom Smarty'
                       ]
        };

Teacher:
        Alex Trump
        George Magic
        Pat Golder
Student:
        Amanda Torry
        Nick Popler
        Jonny Sleeper
        Natalie Simpson
        Tom Smarty
```